# what kind of surface is $f(x,y,z)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, surfaces

How can we check what kind of surface is $f(x,y,z)=0$ with $f(x,y,z)=x^2+3y^2+4yz+3z^2+12\sqrt2y+8\sqrt2z+2x+27$ ?

Comment: It is a [Quadric surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric). Here is a [classification](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticSurface.html).

Comment: Ahh ok! If I calculated everything correctly, it is an ellipsoid @TitoEliatron

Comment: Is there a way, an online calculator so that I can check that? @TitoEliatron

Comment: Maybe this [Applet of GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/qAzgRphm)

Comment: @MaryStar Wait a minute. There are no real points satisfying this equation.

Comment: So is it not an ellipsoid? @Raffaele

Comment: @MaryStar It is an imaginary quadric https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+x%5E2+%2B+3+y%5E2+%2B+4+y+z+%2B+3+z%5E2+%2B+12+Sqrt%5B2%5D+y+%2B+8+Sqrt%5B2%5D+z+%2B+2+x+%2B+27+%3D%3D+++0